# couldn't find projects made with oop concept in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was searching for projects as a reference that are developed with the object oriented concept,class,object,encapsulation,inheritance...
But i couldn't find any that apply these oop concepts,using vb.net of course since I'm vb.net fan.
Can you give me a link if there is any project that fulfills my programming wish?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some books are attached with example projects, as well as some internet lessons like [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8825/Object-Oriented-Programming-In-VB-NET) and [THIS](http://www.studyvb.com/Object-Oriented-Programming.html), will be a good start to help you write your own code.

Comment: Thank you Ala for the resources but i really needed a database application that uses oop,i didn't mention it ofcourse,my fault.All the projects that i have downloaded and checked are like a procedural programming.Please help me out.

Comment: @user2389098, I advice you learn it separated, OOP concepts in The programming language, Database engineering and design, and then the bridge between The application and  the database, Say, ADO or LinkToSQL or whatever. I know DB have OOP and have some concepts in share. But it doesn't mean that you have to learn it in one example.. But the eggs in the basket one by one. 
After that you will find yourself understands the whole image.